# how can I get all the date from a multiple pages from a json api?

Tags: javascript, json, api, vue.js, vuejs2

There are 61 pages in this json file but with this call I only get the first page of it?
How can I get all of them, please?
Is there a loop or another way to use axios?

```
  <template>
  <div id="app">
    
      <thead>
     
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      {{items}}
      </tbody>

  
  </div>

</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      items:[]
    }
  },


  created() {
    axios.get(`https://zbeta2.mykuwaitnet.net/backend/en/api/v2/media-center/press-release/?page=2&page_size=12&type=5`)
    .then(response => {
     
      this.items = response
    })
    
  }
}

</script>
```

Comment: This is specific to API you use, not anything else. This depends on `page` and `page_size` params, doesn't it? Did you try changing them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try without `?page=2&page_size=12&type=5`:

```
axios.get(`https://zbeta2.mykuwaitnet.net/backend/en/api/v2/media-center/press-release/`)
```

or you can set number of articles per page you want to receive (in your case 61 pages with 12 articles on each):

```
axios.get(`https://zbeta2.mykuwaitnet.net/backend/en/api/v2/media-center/press-release/?page=1&page_size=732&type=5`)
```

Comment: thanks but no luck, same result

Comment: Ahh :(  did you try without `?type=5` also?